# Add get_option to jquery

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery, options, radio

I have created a settings page that contains various radio button options for a custom plugin.

A radio button I've created is to 'display dots' with the values yes or no.
I can get use the value any other time except in the jQuery function below.

I would like to get the value of the option to use for 'dots' in the jQuery function below.

jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.single-item').slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: ***OPTION VALUE HERE (true or false)***
  });
});
```

To display the radio buttons I'm using:

```
 <input type="radio" name="testimonial_bullet" id="mws_testimonial_bullet_yes" value="" checked="checked">Yes
 <input type="radio" name="testimonial_bullet" id="mws_testimonial_bullet_no" value="no" <?php if (checked( get_option('testimonial_bullet'), 'no' )); ?> />No
```

To get the get_option value, I'm using:

```
if (get_option('testimonial_bullet') == 'no') {
 // code here
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You could use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I never see you writing these things as an answer. Just wanted to start to write a nice answer when I saw, Howdy was here already. Wouldnt it be better to write a answer, so people can see it better and mark the question as answered and all this stuff?

Comment: @websupporter I want to help people solve their issues or push people in the right direction but sometimes I don't have the time to write descriptive answers. My comments are usually to push OP in the right direction and allows somebody to put in the time I can't to answer the question. In this case, the codex does a good job at explaining how to use the function but I think it would be cheap to copy / paste the codex into an answer. Comments are by no means a definitive answer so you shouldn't be discouraged from answering if a comment points out something.

Comment: fair enough. well i quickly wrote an answer. i understand the time limitations and stuff. i just felt strange, hmmm... there should be an answer as "answer" but he gave it already. man, he does this quite often. so, now i know :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just by knowing about wp_localize_script() would of given me an idea where to look etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyway, basically Hody_McGee gave the answer in his comment: You could use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).
As it states in the Codex:

> [`wp_localize_script()`] can be used to make any data available to
>   your script that you can normally only get from the server side of
>   WordPress.

### How do we do this?

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
function register_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle', 'path-to-file', array( 'jquery' ) );
    $phpInfo = array(
        'testimonial_bullet' => get_option( 'testimonial_bullet' )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'phpInfo', $phpInfo );
}
?>
```

You extend your function, where you enqueue your script (you enqueue it, right?). After you've did this (or you've registered it), you can use `wp_localize_script()` to pass an object to this script. In our case, we create an array `$phpInfo`, which contains the information of the option.

In your script, you can now retrieve the passed content:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if( phpInfo.testimonial_bullet == 'no' )
    var d = '---';
  else
    var d = '...';

  jQuery('.single-item').slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: d
  });
});
```

### Well, but I don't enqueue

I add this, because I see the `<script>`-Tag, so these information might be interesting. First of all, you should. Its easy and good practice. Have a look into [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). It you still think, it might be better to write it in the *header.php* or *foorter.php*, of course there might be reasons to do so. In this case, you can simply retrieve the information like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      if( '<?php echo get_option( 'testimonial_bullet' ); ?>' == 'no' )
        var d = '---';
      else
        var d = '...';

      jQuery('.single-item').slick({
        arrows: true,
        dots: d
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! works a charm! I do enqueue my custom scripts :) I was just playing around in a dev environment.